# Conditional symbols doesn't work

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, conditional-compilation

I have a class library contains the following code snippet:

```
#if (DEBUG && CLOUD)
    return "DEBUG && CLOUD";
#elif (DEBUG && !CLOUD)
    return "DEBUG";
#else
    return "Release";
#endif
```

When I reference this library into my application I got only DEBUG or Release as returns, even if CLOUD is defined.

Comment: Is CLOUD defined for your library or only for your application?

Comment: CLOUD is defined for your the library only.

Comment: Can you show the conditional symbols textbox from the project settings of that library?

Comment: conditional symbols textbox contains SAMPLE;CLOUD;GPU

Comment: And this is for the Debug or Release build? I've pasted the above code snippet into a program of my own, and it seems to work according to specifications.

Comment: @Patrick He said that the CLOUD symbol was defined for the library, which seems to be correct.

Comment: The question says that he has a class library that contains that code snippet, so I would assume this is in the library.

Comment: finally I got the reason. going to add it as an answer; thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is so weird, so I went to the solution properties, under the configuration properties tab. I shocked by what Visual Studio do.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Case #1:

```
#define DEBUG 1
#define CLOUD 1
```

--> `return "DEBUG && CLOUD";`

Case #2:

```
#define DEBUG
#define CLOUD
```

--> `return "Release";`

From this example one can learn that `#if (cond)` evaluates a numeric condition.

If you want to check for definition only you should do:

```
#if defined DEBUG && defined CLOUD
```

Comment: The question is about C#, not C/C++. Your answer applies to C/C++. In C#, #if [works somewhat differently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx).